# Changing / Reposition website actual URL with PHP

Tags: php

I wonder if I can change the website actual `URL` by using `PHP`.

E.g. Original URL:

> www.domain.com/abc

Can it be changed to:

> abc.domain.com

but showing the content from the original URL?

Comment: Please do basic research on well known problems before you ask on SO.

Comment: it's not very clear wheter /abc subfolder should redirect visitor to abc.domain.com, or abc.domain.com should show contents of /abc subfolder

Answer (score -1):

Yes,
Following are the steps

Add entry for **abc.domain.com** in apache host file, which is bound to **/abc** folder

Done!

Comment: it's not very clear wheter /abc subfolder should redirect visitor to abc.domain.com, or abc.domain.com should show contents of /abc subfolder
@codemirror mod_rewrite is not "with PHP" though